# iOS 7 with google chrome

Tags: support

I don't know why Google jumped to having a desktop version but is there away to go back to the mobile version? I have the iPhone 5s with the new update I prefer the mobile version better then the desktop one on my iPhone

Answer (score 2):

Google did nothing, Stack Exchange sites can be viewed both in a mobile and full site version.

You accidentally tapped the 'full site' link in the footer. There is a corresponding 'mobile' link in the full site footer, tap that and get back to the mobile view:

[image: mobile link]

The preference is stored in a cookie, per site.